# using firebase to save and retrieve user profile data

Tags: swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've recently been designing an IOS app with firebase. It's supposed to be a messaging app. I managed to get the authentication process to work using facebook login and email login. I was also able to save a user profile page information onto firebase database when logging in with Facebook and was able to retrieve that data from firebase and present it back to the app. However, when I tried to retrieve the same data using email login, the app crashes. It shows a thread 1: signal SIGABRT error. The console message was

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x110c70cf0

Here's the following code:

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

```
    let userSignedIn = Auth.auth().currentUser

    // to retrieve user info from firebase and show it on app profile page
    var refHandle = self.ref.child("users").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let usersDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        print(usersDict)

        let userDetails = usersDict?.object(forKey: self.user!.uid)

        print(userDetails)

        if self.ageTextfield.placeholder?.lowercased() == "age" {

            self.ageTextfield.text = (userDetails as AnyObject).object(forKey: "age") as! String

        }

        if self.sexTextfield.placeholder?.lowercased() == "sex" {

            self.sexTextfield.text = (userDetails as AnyObject).object(forKey: "sex") as! String
        }

        if self.nameTextfield.placeholder?.lowercased() == "name" {

            self.nameTextfield.text = (userDetails as AnyObject).object(forKey: "name") as! String
        }

        if self.occupationTextfield.placeholder?.lowercased() == "occupation" {

            self.occupationTextfield.text = (userDetails as AnyObject).object(forKey: "occupation") as! String
        }

        if self.hobbiesTextview.text.lowercased() == "hobbies" {

            self.hobbiesTextview.text = (userDetails as AnyObject).object(forKey: "hobbies") as! String
        }

    })
```

I used exception Breakpoint and the following line was highlighted:

```
self.ageTextfield.text = (userDetails as AnyObject).object(forKey: "age") as! String
```

Please let me know what I did wrong.

Comment: It looks like your `userDetails` doesn't contain an `age` key.

Comment: Can you show the printed log

Comment: Hi, it does. My firebase database keys are as follows:  AV4RFwIlSNdnryfPPCl6SfLOzBZ2
age: "23"
hobbies: "Run"
name: 
"Rick Sanchez"
occupation: "doctor"
sex: 60

Comment: This is from the console printout:      2018-05-10 22:03:04.486269+0300 Yala 2018[54278:1247721] -[NSNull objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x108deccf0
2018-05-10 22:03:04.586274+0300 Yala 2018[54278:1247721] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x108deccf0'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: nevermind, I solved the problem. Apparently i didn't realize i was using ChildAutoId each time i logged in. Should have used child(user: uid) instead when referencing the database